# What is the most efficient data type to store probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, probability-distribution, efficiency, storage

In ML we often have to store a huge amount of values ranging from 0 to 1, mostly being probabilities. The most common data structure to do so seems to be a floating point? Indeed, the range of floating points is huge. This makes them imprecise in the desired interval and inefficient, right?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098291/what-data-type-should-be-used-for-a-probability) suggests using the biggest integer value to represent a 1 and the smallest for 0. Also, it points to the [Q number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29), where all bits can be chosen as fractional, which sounds very efficient.

Why have these data types still not found their ways into numpy, tensorflow etc.? Am I missing something?